# Attaching jQuery plugin calls to dynamically loaded elements via jQuery,on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a portion of code that is dynamically loaded via an AJAX call by appending the result to a parent element, similar to this:

```
<div class="parent">
     <!-- Inner content loaded dynamically -->
     <div class="child">
     </div>
     <div class="child">
     </div>
     <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Now, in order to hook up a mouseover event, I would do something like this:

```
$(".parent").on("mouseenter", ".child", function(){
 //Do fun stuff here
}

$(".parent").on("mouseleave", ".child", function(){
 //Undo fun stuff here
}
```

This works well enough for standard functions, but I want to attach this to a third-party plugin (in my case, [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html), but really any plugin) -

The syntax for attaching the HoverIntent plugin is as so:

```
$(".child").hoverIntent( makeTall, makeShort )
```

... but I want this to work for my dynamic content that was not available at the time the document initially loaded, and something like `$(".parent").on("hoverIntent", ".child", function(){});` doesn't seem to be the right way to do this.

What is the correct approach to applying a plugin to elements loaded after the initial `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to just explicitly apply the plugin(s) in the "success" handler(s) of your ajax calls.

Comment: The plugin probably uses `$(you_passed_selector).hover()` as its hook, you can just change the plugin to use `$(document).on('hover', you_passed_selector, function() {});`. Or like previously stated easiest way to to bind on new elements when added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jquery `.on` works by monitoring events on a parent object and then calling the handler if the event originated from a matched child selector. In your case, however, the event you want to monitor is that the element changed

Browsers fire the onchange event for input elements only (because they can be changed by a user).

If any other element changes, it must be because of javascript, hence you can call functions after created new content.

```
$(".child", parentElementContext).hoverIntent( makeTall, makeShort )
```

There are 2 practical solutions

1) What i typically do is create an init method that takes a context (such as the document).

```
MyPage.init = function(context) {
    $('.selector', context).hoverIntent();
    $('.other', context).dialog(); // any other plugins
};
```

Then I manually call init when I update the DOM (because i dont always need to call init when I update the dom)

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data){ 
     var context = $('.parent'); 
     context.html(data);
     MyPage.init(context); //calls hoverIntent and other plugins
  }
});
```

2) If you really need to monitor everything, you can use this plugin
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/

and then `$('.parent').on('valuechange', function() { /* init plugins*/}`

Comment: To anyone: When calling `MyPage.init(context);` in this way, would it be correct to say that  `$('.selector', context).hoverIntent();$('.other', context).dialog(); // any other plugins` all get called, even if I only need `hoverIntent` on this page and not `dialog`? If this is so, wouldn't it be grossly inefficient?

Answer (score 4):

I have used the [jQuery Livequery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) in the past to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use live to attach event to element that will be in the DOM right now or in the future.

```
$(".parent .child").live("mouseover", function(){
    //Do fun stuff here
}).live("mouseout", function(){
    //Undo fun stuff here
});
```

so your plugin could look like this

```
$.fn.hoverIntent = function(mouseover, mouseout) {
    this.live("mouseover", mouseover).live("mouseout", mouseout);
    return this;
};
```

and you can call this plugin

```
$(".parent .child").hoverIntent(makeTall, makeShort).load("other_page.php");
```

Comment: `$(".parent .child").live(...)` is the same as `$(".parent").on("mouseenter", ".child", ...)` and `on` is the new way to do it.