# how to add shiftcheckbox to dynamic generated checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, shift

Use [this jQuery shiftbox plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/shiftcheckbox/) plugin or [this one](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2009/07/02/jquery-shiftcheckbox-plugin/).

**in JS**

```
for (var hidx in hosts) {
        var h = hosts[hidx];
        var line_html = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="input shiftCheckbox"  value = "'+ hidx +'" data-fullname="'+ h +'"></input></td><td>' + h + '</td> </tr>';
        tbody_hosts.append($(line_html));
}
```

This is dynamically generated.

**in HTML**

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.shiftcheckbox.js" type= "text/javascript" ></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" >       
    $(document).ready (function() {
        $('.shiftCheckbox').shiftcheckbox();
    });
</script>
```

Why it does not work? Because it is dynamic?

Comment: You're initialising your shiftcheckbox functionality before the checkboxes exist. Instead of declaring it inside a document.ready block find a way of adding it after your dynamic content has been added to the dom. There are other options too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690739/attaching-jquery-plugin-calls-to-dynamically-loaded-elements-via-jquery-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the event after appending element as you can not delegate most of the jquery plugins:

```
for (var hidx in hosts) {
    var h = hosts[hidx];
    var line_html = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="input shiftCheckbox"  value = "'+ hidx +'" data-fullname="'+ h +'"></input></td><td>' + h + '</td> </tr>';
    tbody_hosts.append($(line_html));

    tbody_hosts.find('.shiftCheckbox').shiftcheckbox();
}
```

Comment: that's what i want, Zan!

Comment: @w.jingwei: glad it helps. don't forget to accept the answer :)